# How can I upload my files to my static server from a production server?

Tags: django, file-upload

I have django and django's admin setup on my production box. This means that all file uploads are stored on the production box, all the media is stored there.

I have a separate server for files now ( different box, ip ). I want to upload my files there. What are the advantages and disadvantages of these methods I've thought about, and are there "better" methods you can suggest?

1. Setting up a script to do an `rsync` on the production box after a file is uploaded to the static server.
2. Setting up a permanent mount on the production box, by using a fileserver on the static media box such as nfs/samba/ssh-fs and then using the location of the mount as the `upload_to` path on the production box

Information: Both servers run debian.

**EDIT**: Prometheus from #django suggested http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-file-storage/

Comment: hey! what did you end up doing? Just curious. Going Fabric way or ...

Answer (score 2):

I use [**Fabric**](http://docs.fabfile.org/0.9.2/). Especially of interest to you would be **[fabric.contrib.project.rsync_project()](http://docs.fabfile.org/0.9.2/api/contrib/project.html)**.

To Paraphrase -

> Fabric is a Python library and
>   command-line tool for streamlining the
>   use of SSH for **Application Deployment**
>   or systems administration tasks.

First use `fabric.contrib.project.upload_project()` to upload the entire project directory. From then on, bank on using `fabric.contrib.project.rsync_project`. to sync the project with local version. Also of special interest is that this uses unix `rsync` underneath & uses the secure `scp` to transfer `.tar.gz` data.

I guess this takes care of your needs. There might not be a need to setup a permanent  mount etc.

Comment: I only need this for static media though, I'm not actually deploying? Or did I misunderstand, and that stuff still applies?

Comment: Oh, but you could still use the method I suggested to keep your static data in sync. It doesn't need to be a Django project only.

Comment: Also wouln't a "permanent mount on the production box" be a security issue? How would data move from one server to other? Is it encrypted? Instead, since your task is to sync both machines, rsync was built for this kind of job. secure & highly optimal. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync

Answer (score 1):

If your static media is derived from your development process, then Fabric is the way to go.  It can automate the deployment and replication of anything-- data, application files, even static database dumps-- from anywhere to anywhere.

If your static media is derived from your application server's operation-- generated PDFs and images, uploads from your users, compiled binaries (I had a customer who wanted that, a Django app that would take in raw x86 assembly and return a compiled and linked binary)-- then you want to use [Django Storages](http://bitbucket.org/david/django-storages/wiki/Home), an app that abstracts the actual storage of content for any ImageField or FileField (or anything with a Python File-like interface).  It has support for storing them in databases, to Amazon S3, via FTP, and a few others.